# Is there a way to bring a running mobile device into focus or run it in the foreground using appium

Tags: java, android, android-studio, appium

I am running an appium script on an Android emulator from via Android studio device manager. I want to see the device on the screen when my appium test is running on it, so I manually click the device icon in the taskbar to bring the device to the foreground so it can be in focus. No issues with that.

Now, sometimes I forget to bring the device to the foreground before running the script, so whilst the script is running, I quickly bring it to focus manually. Is there a way programmatically bring the running device to the foreground?

I easily achieve this with selenium webdriver to bring a browser tab into focus by doing this:

```
String window = driver.getWindowHandle();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('Test')");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().window(window);
```

This is not working in appium. Is there a way to achieve a similar result with appium? Or perhaps, Is there some settings in Android studio to automatically bring the running device into focus?

It's a maven project and I am running the test on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to create a gradle run configuration that would use some kind of terminal script that would focus the emulator window by name? Like running `wmctrl` on Linux.

You would probably have to create a focussed question here if you would get stuck on any of these steps though. As I don't even know what OS you are on.

Comment: Although the Android Emulator also has a setting that puts it always on front. So if you just close the emulator and open it, that would also suffice right? Or do you have multiple emulators? In that case...yeah, more difficult.

Comment: I am running just one emulator at a time. Focusing it manually s not a problem. Is there some setting in Android studio to automatically bring the running device into focus? If not, can it be done via my appium script?

Comment: Its a maven project running on macOS

Comment: Well like this I meant https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJqjO.png

Comment: I get what you mean. The "emulator always on top" setting leaves the emulator on the screen permanently. If minimised to the taskbar, it doesn't automatically come to the foreground when the script is running